# How do I sort a list of ages in prolog?

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

I try to order a list of relatives by their age—from highest to lowest in Prolog:

```
born(kate,date(11,2,1960)).
born(marc,date(11,2,1961)).
born(I,date(9,3,1962)).
born(michel,date(24,4,1963)).
born(harry,date(26,5,1964)).
born(jess,date(16,1,1965)).
born(ruth,date(26,9,1966)).
born(fran,date(4,3,1967)).
```

The result should be one list: `[kate,marc,I,michel,harry,jess,ruth,fran]`.

I try this code fragment by @CapelliC:

```
pairs_values([], []).
pairs_values([_-V|T0], [V|T]) :-
    pairs_values(T0, T).

by_date(Sorted) :-
  findall(Date-Person, born(Person,Date), List),
  keysort(List, Pairs),
  pairs_values(Pairs, Sorted).
```

But this code does not order it.
I need to do it in ciao Prolog.

Comment: and the reason for downvote is ... ?

Comment: @Dmitri: There is nothing specific to Ciao in this question, thus the tag is not appropriate. Reserve the tag to those questions where something specific is asked.

Answer (score 3):

We can do it in SWi-Prolog, using some builtin:

```
by_date(Sorted) :-
  findall(Date-Person, born(Person,Date), List),
  keysort(List, Pairs),
  pairs_values(Pairs, Sorted).
```

**edit**: pairs_values it's really simple: here the SWI-Prolog snippet

```
%%  pairs_values(+Pairs, -Values) is det.
%
%   Remove the keys  from  a  list   of  Key-Value  pairs.  Same  as
%   pairs_keys_values(Pairs, _, Values)

pairs_values([], []).
pairs_values([_-V|T0], [V|T]) :-
    pairs_values(T0, T).
```

Comment: I try this in "ciao prolog" but it throws one error "existence error: procedure:user:pairs_values/2 does not exist"

Comment: I need to do it  in "ciao Prolog", im sorry.

Comment: Even easier: `findall(Date-P, born(P,Date), L0), keysort(L0,L1), findall(P, member(_-P,L1), L2).`

Comment: @larsman: interesting, and could also be more efficient. Without garbage collection (I don't know if Ciao Prolog has any), findall uses the min space required.

Comment: I definitely would use `sort/2` in place of `keysort/2` since `sort/2` removes duplicates and the (quasi random) order of persons of same age. I really would like to use `setof/3`, but it fails (for some good reasons) when `born/2` does not have a solution - instead of giving an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** The sequence you get **is** sorted—but by a sorting criterion that you didn't expect!

Let's run [Ciao Prolog](http://ciao-lang.org/) and try to reproduce the weird behavior the OP observed!

```
$ ciao
Ciao 1.14.2-13646: Mon Aug 15 10:15:33 CEST 2011
?- compile(dmy_vs_ymd).
{Reading /home/stefan/Prolog/dmy_vs_ymd.pl
WARNING: (lns 3-3) [I] - singleton variables in born/2
}
yes
?- by_date(S).
S = [fran,_,kate,marc,jess,michel,harry,ruth] ? ;
no
```

It appears that *every single element* is misplaced—quite a considerable difference:)

- expected: `[kate,marc,I,michel,harry,jess,ruth,fran]`
- observed: `[fran,_,kate,marc,jess,michel,harry,ruth]`

Let's reorder the facts like
`[fran,_,kate,marc,jess,michel,harry,ruth]` and examine:

```
born(fran  , date( 4, 03, 1967)).
born(I     , date( 9, 03, 1962)).
born(kate  , date(11, 02, 1960)).%\_______________________________________________
born(marc  , date(11, 02, 1961)).%/  equal primary & secondary, different tertiary
born(jess  , date(16, 01, 1965)).
born(michel, date(24, 04, 1963)).
born(harry , date(26, 05, 1964)).%\____________________________________
born(ruth  , date(26, 09, 1966)).%/  equal primary, different secondary
%                 ^^  ^^  ^^^^
%                 ||  ||  ||||
%                 ||  ||  \+++------- tertiary sorting criterion
%                 ||  ||
%                 ||  \+------------ secondary sorting criterion
%                 ||
%                 \+------------------ primary sorting criterion
```

The key? **Standard order of terms!** Quoting the [relevant part](https://ciao-lang.org/docs/1.14/13646/CiaoDE-1.14.2-13646_ciao.html/term_compare.html) of the [Ciao Prolog manual](https://ciao-lang.org/docs/1.14/13646/CiaoDE-1.14.2-13646_ciao.html/ciao.html):

> Compound terms, ordered first by arity, then by the name of the principal functor, **then by the arguments in left-to-right order**. Recall that lists are equivalent to compound terms with principal functor `'.'/2`.

Consider the goal `findall(Date-Person, born(Person,Date), List)` in the definition of `by_date/1`. By putting `Date` before `Person` in `Date-Person` makes it the primary criterion. For the comparison of two `date/3` compound terms, the standard order is employed.

To determine the relative position of two `date/3` compounds in the standard order of terms, Prolog uses up to three criteria:

1. `Day`:   If `Day` is decisive, `Month` and `Year` are both irrelevant.
2. `Month`: If `Day` is indecisive, but `Month` is decisive, then `Year` is irrelevant.
3. `Year`: Only if `Day` and `Month` are *both* indecisive, `Year` is even looked at.

> So, can we solve the "sort by decreasing age" problem?  And how?

*Yes!*
Follow [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and migrate from `date(Day,Month,Year)` to `date(Year,Month,Day)`!

```
born(fran  ,date(1967,3, 4)).
born(I,     date(1962,3, 9)).
born(kate  ,date(1960,2,11)).
born(marc  ,date(1961,2,11)).
born(jess  ,date(1965,1,16)).
born(michel,date(1963,4,24)).
born(harry, date(1964,5,26)).
born(ruth,  date(1966,9,26)).
```

Sample query:

```
?- by_date(S).
S = [kate,marc,_,michel,harry,jess,ruth,fran].
```

Hmm... Are  we done yet?

- expected: `[kate,marc,I,michel,harry,jess,ruth,fran]`
- observed: `[kate,marc,_,michel,harry,jess,ruth,fran]`

Not quite 100%... `I` is a variable—we actually wanted a constant; replace it with the atom `i`.
This incognito variable was the reason for getting the "singleton variable" warning we got at the start of our Ciao Prolog session. HTH!