# How to sort the atoms in descending order and print it out

Tags: sorting, prolog

```
%travelto(Traveller, Travelling_to, Distance, Cost)
travelto(nella,ryan,120,35).
travelto(jamie,lyla,50,10).
travelto(tyran,john,55,25).
travelto(maria,karolina,350,55).
travelto(leo,anna,250,20).
travelto(lyla,josh,300,45).
travelto(martin,john,250,55).
travelto(leo,najma,100,20).
travelto(diana,kyle,230,15).
travelto(michael,lucy,90,15).
travelto(sam,kate,300,40).
travelto(jason,cindy,170,26).
travelto(julia,nayma,110,10).

sortList(Traveller):-
   findall(Traveller-Cost,travelto(Traveller,_,_,Cost),List),
   keysort(List,Answer),
   print([Answer]),
   fail.
```

The information above is part of the facts which is from my database. I want to create a rule which will allow the user to type in a list of atoms(traveler names) and return a descending list of the names by cost. I read some documentation from [swi-prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=builtinlist) and I also tried searching into [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654645/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-ages-in-prolog). The rule which I created is above and I guess it is wrong. I tried reading a lot and I still couldn't figure out what I should do. Can someone please help me with the problem I am facing right now?

Below is the example of the query I want to type and example of the return I want to get.

```
?-sortList([martin,jamie,diana,tyran,nella]). %query I want to type in
[martin,nella,tyran,diana,jamie] %return I am expecting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keysort/2` sorts by key.  In your pairs `Traveller-Cost` the traveller is the key.  If you want to keysort by cost your pairs must be inverted.

After sorting you can extract the values (travellers) from the pairs using `pair_values/2`.

Look at library [pairs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs) for more info.